# lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError while trying to read_excel using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've a spreadsheet (~50 mb) with multiple sheets, and I'm trying to read it using pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('compiled_output.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

I'm not sure why it's throwing `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError`; I've done this many times before. I also tried passing `engine=openpyxl`, downgraded to `pandas==1.2.4` but I get the same error:

```sh
df = pd.read_excel('compiled_output.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 336, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1131, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 475, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 391, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 486, in load_workbook
    return load_workbook(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 282, in read
    self.read_worksheets()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 216, in read_worksheets
    rels = get_dependents(self.archive, rels_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/packaging/relationship.py", line 131, in get_dependents
    node = fromstring(src)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3237, in lxml.etree.fromstring
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1896, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1784, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1141, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 615, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 725, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 654, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "<string>", line 2
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: internal error: Huge input lookup, line 2, column 12753697
```

Comment: xlsx files are basically zip files with images, metadata, etc packaged together. The data itself is stored in xml, which is why you're seeing an exception generated by lxml.

Comment: Apparently, the XML is too large to parse. In lxml, you'd set the `huge_tree` option, but I don't think it's available through Pandas. Similar question: [python - Parsing huge XML files with Pandas pd.from_xml() and lxml - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71466979/parsing-huge-xml-files-with-pandas-pd-from-xml-and-lxml)